# I have been practicing A star search algorithm in python with an example of my own but the answer comes wrong with my algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, search, a-star

The tree nodes are displayed in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/be27s.jpg Along with the heuristics.

```
def astaralgo():
   global tree, heuristic      
   openedlist = [['A', 390]]
   closedlist = []          

   #Finding the first visited node and the rest
   while True:
       fn =  [i[1] for i in openedlist]             
       chosen_index = fn.index(min(fn))             
       node = openedlist[chosen_index][0]         
       closedlist.append(openedlist[chosen_index])  
       del openedlist[chosen_index]                 
       if closedlist[-1][0] == 'Z':                
           break
       
       for item in tree[node]:
           if item[0] in [closedlist_item[0] for closedlist_item in closedlist]:  
               continue                                 
           cost.update({item[0]: cost[node] + item[1]}) 
           fn_node = cost[node] + heuristic[item[0]] + item[1] 
           temp = [item[0], fn_node] 
           openedlist.append(temp)
    
   #Optimal path search 
   trace_node = 'Z'
   optimal_path = ['Z']    
   for i in range(len(closedlist)-2, -1, -1):    
       check_node = closedlist[i][0]            
       if trace_node in [children[0] for children in tree[check_node]]: 
           children_costs = [temp[1] for temp in tree[check_node]]
           children_nodes = [temp[0] for temp in tree[check_node]]
           
           if cost[check_node] + children_costs[children_nodes.index(trace_node)] == cost[trace_node]: 
               optimal_path.append(check_node)          
               trace_node = check_node                  
  
   optimal_path.reverse()       
   return closedlist, optimal_path
```

Here is the code for it. Everything works perfectly but the answer comes out wrong. The output is below

```
Nodes visited with the optimal path: [['A', 390], ['D', 390], ['C', 396], ['F', 405], ['G', 414], ['B', 435], ['F', 448], ['J', 453], ['Z', 447]]
Chosen Optimal path from A to Z: ['A', 'D', 'G', 'J', 'Z']
```

But this is not the optimal path.

Comment: What is the correct path? Where does your implementation diverge from it? What is the internal state when you single-step through it to the point of divergence?

Comment: Would help if you provided full context. In particular, values for:  `tree`, `heuristic` and `cost`.

Comment: I added the picture of the example in the imgur link along with the values of all